# Python pip, move packages to virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Is it possible to move all the installed packages via pip in system's python library to a virtualenv location? I know that using pip freeze, one can get the list of all packages and can install them later via pip in the virtualenv. But is it possible just to copy these files?

Comment: Just copy the site-packages folder contents over, should work *on the same machine*.

Comment: You can use `--system-site-packages` when you create the environment to allow access to them. `--always-copy` will make a copy of them; it defaults to making a symlink.